# 'npm run coverage' not running with mocha

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, code-coverage, istanbul

I'm trying to run Istanbul with mocha on a express.js application

Every time I run the cmd npm run coverage I get this error in the cmd:

```
Unable to resolve file [node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha]
Try "istanbul help" for usage
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! dabl-demo@1.0.0 coverage: `istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the dabl-demo@1.0.0 coverage script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\donallane\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-10T11_55_29_922Z-debug.log
```

I have updated the latest version of npm.. rerun the cmd npm install.. 
Uninstalled and reinstalled the node_modules directory.

The cmd npm run coverage still will not create a coverage folder and populate it with all my project files..

Any help would be great.. Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "dabl-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "coverage": "istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
    "showcoverage": "start coverage/lcov-report/index.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "connect": "^3.6.5",
    "consolidate": "^0.15.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "method-override": "^2.3.10",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "mysql2": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1",
    "nunjucks": "^3.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg": "^7.4.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "sequelize": "^4.22.5",
    "sequelize-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.13"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1",
    "request": "^2.83.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? If yes, look at [this](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/44#issuecomment-57708358) issue on Github. Also look into `nyc`.

Comment: Thanks, I am on windows. However, I want to be able to see all scripts in the browser #

Comment: You mean the code coverage as html? nyc does that, it's just the new cli for istanbul. Set up nyc with the html reporter.

Comment: Yes exactly dude.. Thanks, is there any particular cmd for getting html reporting on nyc?

Comment: You do that by setting `--reporter=html`. See [here](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#running-reports). Usually, you configure the entire thing in package.json or something similar. You then make sure `html` is in the `reporter` array.

Comment: Spot on thank you.. I knew there was an easier solution!!